# How to ajax load just html, without loading image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using ajax to load html document on the web (to extract data automatically), like so:

```
$.ajax({
url:'http://example.com/index.php',
crossDomain: true,
accepts:"html",
dataType:"html"});
```

**I expect it to load the html document only.** However all images attached to the document are loaded too. By inspecting browser's network activity via developer console, I can see that images are being request along.

*Example of returned html document.*

```
<html>
<body>
<div>Data I wanted: item price, stock availability etc.</div>
<img src="../img/very-large-image.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

Browser is making request for '../img/very-large-image.jpg' after receiving the html doc.

**Is there a way to load HTML doc without the browser making request for the image?**  I would like to load html only. This issue affect my app performance especially when images on that page is large in size.

I have tried searching the internet for answers but haven't found any related articles yet. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: remove the image from the html if it large size

Comment: Rather then skipping the image, which is very hard, try to reduce the size of that image in the first place.

Comment: example.com is not within my control. It's on web, publicly.

Answer (score 2):

1. Images & scripts will start loading after you place it in **DOM**
2. We can remove/modify all images before we place received html into **DOM**

Following function should work.

```
$.ajax({
url:'http://example.com/index.php',
crossDomain: true,
accepts:"html",
dataType:"html",
success:function(data){
       var $html = $(data);
       //Remove src from all images 
       $('img',$html).attr('src','');
       //Now set html to container
       $('#container').html($html);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tested your answer, but browser will start requesting for images once '$(data)' was called.

Comment: Yea, I missed it, by `$(data)` we actually putting into the dom.
I guess we need to replace all image occurrences with regex in `data`.

Comment: I recommend using this [method](https://www.xfive.co/blog/how-to-parse-html-response-without-loading-any-images/?comment=new#comment-12593). Look at Jean-Baptiste comment to make it work as intended though.

The method is based on loading the html into a new DomDocument so that resources are not loaded. It is much faster than the regex solution on relatively big pages.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex replace all occurance of `<head>, <link>, <script>, <style>`, including `background` and `style` attribute from data string returned by ajax load.

REGEX:

```
(<(\b(img|style|script|head|link)\b)(([^>]*\/>)|([^\7]*(<\/\2[^>]*>)))|(<\bimg\b)[^>]*>|(\b(background|style)\b=\s*"[^"]*"))
```

Test regex: https://regex101.com/r/nB1oP5/1

I hope there is a a better way to work around (other than using regex replace).

Comment: [You can't really use Regex against Html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/209259).

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegEx. it removes every `src` and `<link href`.

```
this.response.replace(/src=((['][^']*['])|(["][^"]*["]))/igm, "").replace(/<link[^>]*>/igm, "");
```

Comment: [You can't really use Regex against Html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/209259).

Comment: It's not a HTML document yet. it is a response text :)